# getting text messages on my computer from my iphone

Tags: messages

can i look at my text messages from imessage on my computer? because im grounded from my iphone and need to check my messages from friends. any ideas on what I can use?

Comment: What sort of computer do you have? And, if it's a Mac, what version of macOS are you running?

Comment: I'm seriously torn here. On the one hand, this could be a legitimate question. On the other hand, I'm kind of loathe to help you work around a punishment from your parents.